# Segmentation image processing using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to segment my image using the following code.

```
image=imread('mob.jpg');
image = im2bw(image);
L = bwlabel(image,8);% Calculating connected components
mx=max(max(L))
[r,c] = find(L==1);  
rc = [r c];
[sx sy]=size(rc);
n1=zeros(imx,imy); 
for i=1:sx
    x1=rc(i,1);
    y1=rc(i,2);
    n1(x1,y1)=255;
end
imshow(image);
figure,
imshow(n1);
```

This was my input image-
[image]

I wanted to separate it into 2 connected componets-one the actual structure and other `7181`.Instead I am getting `6` components.The first-two  component are-
[image]
[image]

So why is this happening?In all the pics I tested whenever there is a benzene ring it gets separated into another component.How can I just separate it into 2 components -the structure and '7191'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are analyzing the areas of connected **white** pixels in your image, so you get:

- the white background (1)
- the inner area of the benzene ring (1)
- the inner areas of the two `O`s (2)
- the inner areas of the `8` (2)

These are six objects in total.

Invert your image before processing, and you'll get all the lines and letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have another question is there any way I can join all the bonds and remove out the alphabets ?

Comment: @Noober - Yeah, this question that you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934611/line-detection-in-image/30942695#30942695 - There are three good answers that find the lines for you and you haven't accepted any of them.